# Need listing of all relationships of tables SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a ticket that I need to get a listing of all the relationships in one of my tables, I found that fairly easy here - I need to take it one more step - what my manager wants to see is all the tables that directly reference my main patient table, and all the ways those child tables reference all other tables.. Something like: Patient table -> address table then address table is linked to the shipping table, then the shipping table is linked to xx table... so its a huge spiderweb!  has anyone had to accomplish this before?

Comment: Does this help: [How to find all the dependencies of a table in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005698/how-to-find-all-the-dependencies-of-a-table-in-sql-server)?

Answer (score 1):

This will get *all* relations discoverable through FK constraints for a database:

```
USE <your database>
GO

SELECT
  ChildSchema.name AS ChildSchema
 ,Child.name AS ChildTable  
 ,fk.name
 ,ParentSchema.name AS ParentSchema
 ,Parent.name AS ParentTable
FROM
 sys.foreign_keys FK
INNER JOIN
  sys.tables Child
    ON Child.object_id = FK.parent_object_id --Parent here means the "parent" of the FK, not the relation
INNER JOIN
  sys.schemas ChildSchema
    ON ChildSchema.schema_id = Child.schema_id
INNER JOIN
  sys.tables Parent
    ON Parent.object_id = FK.referenced_object_id
INNER JOIN
  sys.schemas ParentSchema
    ON ParentSchema.schema_id = Parent.schema_id
ORDER BY 
  ChildSchema.name
 ,Child.name
GO
```

Comment: BBaird - this is close I can use this to find the primary relationships to my patient table, but i need to take it one step further (Names for example) Patient is linked to address so I would want to see patient -> address, but address may be linked to shipping so I would want to see address->shipping and just go down the line.  I need to identify any table that is directly or non directly connected to the patient table

Comment: That query provides all of the necessary information - it can be changed into a recursive query easily enough.  I'll see if I can get something together later.